# SQL sorting by a column that is a String

Tags: sql, database, string, ssms, sqldatatypes

I am trying to write a query that will sort a column by the number that it is. However, the column is a string, so instead of sorting like 1, 2, 3, it will sort 1, 10, 11, 12, etc. Is there a way to change a column from a string to a number, or even a way to change how it orders the Strings. Here is my code and its output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT draft_number
    FROM NBA_data.dbo.all_seasons
        WHERE draft_year = '2016'
        ORDER BY draft_number;
```

Output:

```
draft_number
1
10
11
18
19
2
20
21
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast draft_number to datatype INT in Order By clause.

```
ORDER BY CAST(draft_number As INT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to change the column type from string to number. Thus you don't have the hassle with every query on that column. Always use the appropriate data type for your data.

```
ALTER TABLE NBA_data.all_seasons ALTER COLUMN draft_number INT;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23324061a0c49d61a0172d46ad74bb77